# How to enable or add records to Public Tags in Salesforce?

Tags: tag

I was able to Enable Personal Tag and assign Records of different objects to it. But couldn't able to see Public Tag anywhere in My Developer ORG setting or anywhere.

Can someone help me on this Query?

Comment: Is there any significance or relation with related to "Topics" for "Tags"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just reading on this - public tags and topics can't be active at the same time.  Topics are default so you need to disable them before you can engage public tags.

Topics seem to be replacing public tags but since you seems you can't really report on either maybe the prudent thing is to hold off until topics are more fully baked.